# Limit/filter return of list from UNIQUE()

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to ask if there is any way to limit the number of values returned from the UNIQUE() function in googlesheets?

For example, based on the below screenshot, I would do

[image]

```
UNIQUE(A2:A)
```

That will return me all year_quarter values in ascending order.

Assuming that row A will contain many quarter values from 2016 to 2020, is there a function, or to use a query, to return the earliest first 4 quarters of column A?

I also tried combining with QUERY() through putting a LIMIT in the SELECT statement, but realize that logic doesn't work out .

If there is a way to flexibly do another selection of all values EXCEPT the first 4 quarters, that would be great.

Appreciate any tips on how to go about doing this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your logic actually should work.

---

To show only (up to) the first 4 results:

```
=QUERY(SORT(UNIQUE(A2:A)),"limit 4")
```

[image]

---

And to exclude the first 4 results:

```
=QUERY(SORT(UNIQUE(A2:A)),"offset 4")
```

[image]

#### Reference:

- [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)
- [SORT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en)

Comment: your solution assumes that the input data is sorted.. but I might have misunderstood the OP's intentions.

Comment: very clever approach :)

Comment: Thank you for the super elegant approach!

Answer (score 3):

### Answer 1:

> Assuming that row A will contain many quarter values from 2016 to
> 2020, is there a function, or to use a query, to return the earliest
> first 4 quarters of column A?

```
=query(unique(A2:A),"Select Col1 where Col1 is not Null Order By Col1 desc limit 4")
```

or if you want to sort them back:

```
=sort(query(unique(A2:A),"Select Col1 where Col1 is not Null Order By Col1 desc limit 4"))
```

[image]

---

### Answer 2:

> If there is a way to flexibly do another selection of all values
> EXCEPT the first 4 quarters, that would be great.

```
=query(unique(A2:A),"Select Col1 where Col1 is not Null Order By Col1 limit " & counta(unique(A2:A))-4)
```

[image]

or if you don't want unique values remove the `unique` part:

```
=query(A2:A,"Select A where A is not Null Order By A limit " & counta(A2:A)-4)
```

Comment: Thank you for breaking down the problem into pieces bit by bit, definitely still learnt something with your approach in terms of thought process!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the simpler and less intense **[SORTN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624)**

```
=SORTN(B2:B,4,2,1,1)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow first time learning SORTN(). Thank you for sharing this!

Comment: If you play around with the `display_ties_mode` you will find that `SORTN` is very flexible. Like using `=SORTN(B2:B,4,3,1,1)` *"Show at most the first n unique rows, but show every duplicate of these rows"*. It will show all rows of earliest (or latest by changing to asc) n quarters *(not easily done using other methods)*.

Comment: Very interesting, but I don't suppose this will be a solution for the 2nd part where I would need to show all unique rows except the first N rows right?